# Why does DISTINCT make this query take 10x longer than without?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, database-performance

I've got this mysql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT post.postId,hash,previewUrl,lastRetrieved
FROM post INNER JOIN (tag as t1,taggedBy as tb1,tag as t2,taggedBy as tb2,tag as t3,taggedBy as tb3)
ON post.id=tb1.postId AND tb1.tagId=t1.id AND post.id=tb2.postId AND tb2.tagId=t2.id AND post.id=tb3.postId AND tb3.tagId=t3.id
WHERE ((t1.name="a" AND t2.name="b") OR t3.name="c") 
ORDER BY post.postId DESC LIMIT 0,100;
```

it takes around 15 seconds to run that query, whereas the same query *without* `DISTINCT` takes less than a second.

---

`EXPLAIN` output for the query *with* `DISTINCT`:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------+------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys       | key     | key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------+------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | post  | index  | PRIMARY             | postId  | 4       | NULL                     |    1 | Using temporary       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tb1   | ref    | PRIMARY,tagId       | PRIMARY | 4       | e621datamirror.post.id   |   13 | Using index; Distinct |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,name,name_2 | PRIMARY | 4       | e621datamirror.tb1.tagId |    1 | Distinct              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tb2   | ref    | PRIMARY,tagId       | PRIMARY | 4       | e621datamirror.post.id   |   13 | Using index; Distinct |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,name,name_2 | PRIMARY | 4       | e621datamirror.tb2.tagId |    1 | Distinct              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tb3   | ref    | PRIMARY,tagId       | PRIMARY | 4       | e621datamirror.post.id   |   13 | Using index; Distinct |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t3    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,name,name_2 | PRIMARY | 4       | e621datamirror.tb3.tagId |    1 | Using where; Distinct |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------+------+-----------------------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

`EXPLAIN` output for the query *without* `DISTINCT`:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys       | key     | key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | post  | index  | PRIMARY             | postId  | 4       | NULL                     |    1 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tb1   | ref    | PRIMARY,tagId       | PRIMARY | 4       | e621datamirror.post.id   |   13 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,name,name_2 | PRIMARY | 4       | e621datamirror.tb1.tagId |    1 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tb2   | ref    | PRIMARY,tagId       | PRIMARY | 4       | e621datamirror.post.id   |   13 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,name,name_2 | PRIMARY | 4       | e621datamirror.tb2.tagId |    1 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tb3   | ref    | PRIMARY,tagId       | PRIMARY | 4       | e621datamirror.post.id   |   13 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t3    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,name,name_2 | PRIMARY | 4       | e621datamirror.tb3.tagId |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------------+---------+---------+--------------------------+------+-------------+
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `postId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `previewUrl` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `lastRetrieved` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `postId` (`postId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hash` (`hash`),
  KEY `postId_2` (`postId`),
  KEY `postId_3` (`postId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=692561 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `tag` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `name_2` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=157876 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE `taggedBy` (
  `postId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tagId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`postId`,`tagId`),
  KEY `tagId` (`tagId`),
  CONSTRAINT `taggedBy_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`postId`) REFERENCES `post` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `taggedBy_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tagId`) REFERENCES `tag` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

---

what causes this query to be so slow? how can I speed it up?

I hope I've given enough information so you guys can give me some meaningful answers. if I've left something out I'll be happy to add it.

Comment: Because `distinct` removes duplicate rows and the database has to do more work.

Comment: instead of doing a select all, distinct does a select all for every row there is to see if there is another value like it.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html this query appears to meet the conditions of making an on-disk temp table. You can check that if that is the case by seeing if the relevant status variable was changed. If so, you want to remove some of the conditions for the creation of such a table because that, as you can imagine, is slow.

Comment: wouldn't DISTINCT here lead to *less* work? it's not like mysql is stupid enough to first select *all* possible results, *then* filter out distinct results, and *then* limiting to 100 items.

I know for a fact mysql is smarter than that, because leaving out the limit makes the query take way *way* longer.

in any case I wouldn't expect a 10x slowdown.

Comment: Try factoring the `DISTINCT` out an additional level?  You'll have to overshoot your inner `LIMIT` to ensure you get the correct number of results though.  i.e. `SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM (SELECT ... LIMIT 1000) LIMIT 100`

Comment: ah, but then the overshoot will be sufficiently big to cause a slowdown. the average tag count per post is 50 or so.

Answer (score 1):

Several things are being discussed, even in @SlimGhost's reasonable (but deleted) answer.

**DISTINCT vs GROUP BY**

Although `GROUP BY` can sometimes be used to replace `DISTINCT`, don't do it; they are meant for different things.

They both require *some* form of extra effort.  (I'll get to the 10x later.)  Both have to discover common values -- either in the entire row (for `DISTINCT`) or for the grouped items.  This can be done in one of at least two ways.  (Probably most engines have these options built in.)  Note that the `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` must logically come after `WHERE`, but before `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.

- Keep some kind of internal associative array as the output is being generated.  This is practical if the the optimizer can see that there won't be "too many" possible different values.
- Sort the output; then dedup or group in a pass over the output.  This works regardless of size.

**ORDER BY + LIMIT**

Notice that the query is doing `DISTINCT` over 4 columns: `post.postId, hash, previewUrl, lastRetrieved`.  It is not obvious whether these are all in `post` or scattered across the 7 tables.  (Please clarify by qualifying every column.)

Let's assume the JOINs need to be done to find the 4 columns.

Let's say there is no `DISTINCT`.  Now, the operations are

1. Walk through `post` in `ORDER BY post.postID` order.
2. For each such row, do the JOINs and check the WHERE.
3. After 100 rows have passed the WHERE, stop.

But with `DISTINCT`, the optimizer can't make such a simplifying assumption in order to stop short.  Instead:

1. Walk through `post` in `ORDER BY post.postID` order.  (Starting with t1/t2/t3 is out of the question because of `OR`.)  Actually, it is unclear whether the optimizer would bother going in this order.
2. For each such row, do the JOINs and check the WHERE.
3. Do something about `DISTINCT`.
4. After 100 rows have passed the WHERE, stop.  Note:  This *may* involve lots more rows from `post` (perhaps 10x?)

Keep in mind that the optimizer knows nothing about whether `postId` is 1:1 with `hash`, etc.  So, it can't make simplifying assumptions.  Suppose there were 200 rows in the JOIN with the smallest `postId`, and the `hash` happened to be in descending order.  Smells like a need for a "sort".

`EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` *might* give you some of these details.

Ouch.  You have both a `id` and `UNIQUE(postid)`?  Get rid of `id` and turn the `postId` into the `PRIMARY KEY`.  This, alone, may speed things up.

What is the `hash` a hash of?

Please use the `JOIN ... ON ...` syntax.

You have 3 indexes on `postId`; get rid of the extra two.

**Why use DISTINCT?**

Now that I see that all the `SELECTed` columns come from the one table, and that they will obviously be easily made distinct, why even consider using `DISTINCT`.

(updates)

**JOIN ON**

```
FROM post INNER JOIN (tag as t1,taggedBy as tb1,...
                   ON post.id=tb1.postId AND tb1.tagId=t1.id AND ...
 -->
FROM post
JOIN tag       AS  t1 ON post.id = tb1.postId
JOIN taggedBy  AS tb1 ON tb2.tagId = t2.id
...  (each ON is next to the JOIN it applies to)
```

**A speedup technique**

```
SELECT p2.postId, p2.hash, p2.previewUrl, p2.lastRetrieved
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT postId           -- Only the PRIMARY KEY
            FROM post
            JOIN ... etc
            WHERE ... ...
            ORDER BY postId
            LIMIT 100
         ) x
    JOIN post AS p2  ON x.postId = p2.id   -- self join for getting rest of fields
    ORDER BY x.postId   -- assuming you need the ordering
```

This puts the `DISTINCT` in the inner query, where you are fetching only the one column (`postId`).  (I am not sure whether this technique will help much in *your* case.)

Comment: those 4 columns are all on the post table, I did post the database schema.

there's a reason postId is separate from id. I don't have full control over postId which makes it a bad choice for foreignkeys. postId might change.

the hash is a hash of a jpeg file usually.

I'm using DISTINCT because not using it returns a lot of duplicate rows. if it's so easy to get 100 unique results you might want to tell me how.

as far as I know I am using JOIN ON syntax?

anyways, thanks for taking the time to write such a thorough answer!

Comment: Can you change `postId` to be the `PRIMARY KEY` and demote `id` to be just an `INDEX`?  (Yes, that will be OK even with `id` being `AUTO_INCREMENT`.)

Comment: An InnoDB `PRIMARY KEY` is 'clustered' with the data; I somewhat need that for performance here.